# Where is the NavigableMap's implementation of put() method inside of TreeSet?

Tags: java

I've just wanted to debug how TreeSet's method add() workds, particulary, how the process of sorting is organized inside of TreeSet.

So when we look inside the TreeSet class, we see method add(E e)

```java
    public boolean add(E e) {
        return m.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
    }
```

Okay, what is **m** variable?

```java
    private transient NavigableMap<E,Object> m;
```

Alright, let's search for implementations of put() method from Map interface... Well... The best thing, which could be found is implementation in TreeMap... But where is the specific implementation for TreeSet?

Comment: *"I've just wanted to debug how TreeSet's method add() workds"* Well, then, do it! What's the problem? When you debug with a **debugger**, simply use the "**Step Into**" action and you'll see the code that is actually executed.

Comment: Look at where `m` gets assigned to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TreeSet` uses `TreeMap` for the implementation of its backing `Map`, as you can see in the constructors:

```
public TreeSet() {
    this(new TreeMap<E,Object>());
}

public TreeSet(Comparator<? super E> comparator) {
    this(new TreeMap<>(comparator));
}
```

Therefore the `TreeMap` implementation of `put()` is used by `TreeSet`.